# How to secure BIRT Report Viewer

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, birt

I need to implement authentication of user for birt report viewer while opening the reports,
so that we should not be able to run the report and user authentication should also be done before opening the report.

Comment: Are you integrate your birt report viewer with web application? I use [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html) in my previous project to prevent the user to access the report before the user's is logged to the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Iswanto San already mentioned in his comment - I would use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html) as well.

But it really depends on your skill set - and what you are deploying your viewer to.

If you use Tomcat - you can create a simple form authentication by following [this step-by-step guide from Deron Eriksson on avajava.com.](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html)

Another option would be to follow what Birt-Exchange recommends by following the [Birt-Exchange guide on security integration with the Actuate BIRT Viewers.](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/wiki/index.php?title=Security_Integration_with_the_Actuate_BIRT_Viewers)

**OR!**
You could integrate security straight in the report itself by following [this simple guide from Balendra15.Wordpress.com.](http://balendra15.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/adding-security-to-birt-reports/)

I hope anything of this is to any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply add an NTLM-authentication (LDAP) filter to the BIRT's web.xml (basic Tomcat config).

More info: https://sites.google.com/site/dynamicdatamining/birt/birt-viewer-security